# ScrollView jumps up to beginning of the page

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-scrollview

in my main layout i have a vertical scroll View that contains three view Flipper,
to see my second and third view Flipper i have to scroll down,which it works perfectly and i can scroll down and see them, BUT when i scroll down and want to flip on my view Flipper ,
it flips but in the same time my scroll View jumps to top of the page, its the same for all my view Flippers
the one thing that i should mention is, as scroll view can host only one direct child, so I put all my XML code inside one Linear layout. is it may cause my problem?
is anybody knows how can i fix it?

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >



                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="263dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff" >

                    <ViewFlipper
                        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
                        android:layout_width="296dp"
                        android:layout_height="88dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/pic53" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/save" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/brazil" />
                    </ViewFlipper>
                </FrameLayout>



                <ViewFlipper
                    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="88dp" >
```

>

```
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="127dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.54"
                            android:background="#ffffff" >



                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/brazil" />
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </ViewFlipper>


                <ViewFlipper
                    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="88dp" >
```

>

```
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="127dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.54"
                            android:background="#ffffff" >



                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/brazil" />
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </ViewFlipper>




                <ViewFlipper
                    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="88dp" >
```

>

```
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >


                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="127dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.54"
                            android:background="#ffffff" >



                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/brazil" />
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </ViewFlipper>

        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem was cause of conjunction of `scrollView` and the `LinearLayout` which contained my `viewFlipper` , so I gave `layout_marginRight` to my `LinearLayout` then it fixed